# Computational Game Theory, Why aren't Nash Equilibrium calculated with rational numbers instead of floating point numbers?

Tags: game-theory, rational-numbers, card-games, nash-equilibrium, floating-point

In algorithms like Counterfactual Regret Minimization/Regret Matching, most implementations are coded using floating point numbers to represent (average) strategies, and the value of the game is usually given as a floating point number. This usually makes these computed values non-exact, which is kind of a bummer.

For example, in Rock Paper Scissors, Nash Equilibrium is (1/3, 1/3, 1/3), but when you try to compute it, of course, you get (0.33333333326, 0.3333333334, 0.333333...).

Another example, in Kuhn Poker, The value of the game is -1/18--a rational number. Even more so, the optimal strategy is also a bunch of rational numbers, so why are we indirectly attacking these problems with floating point numbers?

My understanding is that (currently) rational numbers are not as efficient to perform arithmetic operations (as opposed to IEEE 754) with. But I would definitely rather compute Nash Equilibrium on my computer with the exact values I am supposed to get. Also, this kind of suggests an amazing opportunity to make rational numbers arithmetic extremely efficient to compute with.

Can anyone provide me with some insight on this? I would especially love to have some python code that returns fractions.Fraction(-1, 18) instead of -0.0555555555556131231231.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it, but in a larger setting the integers eventually become impractically large to store/work with, and there is no real way around this fact. Arithmetic on big integers just costs more than arithmetic on small integers (eventually...with a type like "int" it's all the same among numbers representable as an "int"). (Incidentally, what you wrote there is off by significantly more than double precision machine epsilon, so I suspect there is a little bit more going on there.)

Comment: @Ian yeah, that is my understanding. Do you have any further insight?

Comment: Not really? Some software such as Mathematica can give rational number answers if desired.

Comment: Okay, my question is still unanswered yall. I still want to know why we have to settle for less since RPS and Kuhn Poker basically scream "use a(n efficient) rational datatype "

Comment: @Ian My desire is to have SOTA algorithms like CFR/RM implemented efficient with rational number data types, so I get the exact answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Technically, all representable IEEE 754 values except $\pm \infty$ and NaN *are* rational numbers.

Comment: Them being efficient and in rational number arithmetic is not actually possible. There is a reason why we don't normally do that.

Comment: The ABC programming language, a predecessor to Python, actually did use exact rational arithmetic instead of floating point.  For example, if you wrote `6.02214076e23`, you got the exact integer value 602214076000000000000000.  It turned out that arithmetic got *really* slow after accumulating lots of operations, which is why Python has `float`.

Comment: @Ian What is the proof that it's not possible? What is the reason we don't do that?

Comment: @Dan it sounds like you know what IEEE 754 is, but you don't know about CFR/RM correct? Because this is besides the point.

Comment: The proof is from examining how denominators scale when you do procedures like Gaussian elimination.